# Date format error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select 
  (*)
From 
  MISC
WHERE
  TO_DATE(TRANSACTION_TIME, YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6) Between 
  TO_DATE(:Variable1, 'YYYYMMDD') and TO_DATE(:Variable2, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

The transaction time column is CHAR(78) and returns 2017-06-12-12.35.37.444978 as and example. I have been struggling with this for awhile now and getting a variety of errors. With the current setup, I receive

> Error Executing Query: ORA-01821: date format not recognized.

Variable1 = 20170612
Variable2 = 20170615

Comment: But your specified format is different from the actual format? How did you expect it to work?

Comment: Your first `TO_DATE` a) doesn't seem to match the format, and b) isn't in quotes. I would suggest that before you start getting the `BETWEEN` part working, concentrate on the `TO_DATE` part for the `TRANSACTION_TIME`.

Comment: `DATE` data type does not support fractional seconds. Use `TIMESTAMP` as already suggested by APC.

Comment: Specifically: the `.FF6` element is causing the trouble. That is allowed for TIMESTAMP data type, but not for DATE data type. Change ALL THREE occurrences of TO_DATE to TO_TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a timestamp not a date so you need to use `to_timestamp()` not `to_date()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking at the date, then perhaps a simpler version will work:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(SUBSTR(TRANSACTION_TIME, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') Between 
          TO_DATE(:Variable1, 'YYYYMMDD') and TO_DATE(:Variable2, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

Also, why not pass in the variables as dates rather than strings?  That would get around the second conversion.  If they are actually dates, then that might be where the conversion problem is.

Comment: The `YYYY-MM-DD` in the first line should be within single quotes ... ?